# KDE5 Not Connecting to L2TP VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, 16.04, vpn

KDE is refusing to allow me to connect to the server, saying that `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp` is not installed.

Logfile:

```
May  5 11:54:12 BlackHawk NetworkManager[7978]: <info>  [1462474452.6911] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="bb9a44c7-a7a2-4c63-bbcb-8189af52f6fe" name="vpn.example.com" pid=6899 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="The VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.l2tp' was not installed."
```

I have installed all NetworkManager VPN packages, so I'm not sure what the problem is. How do I solve this issue?

---

Installed (relevant) packages:

```
network-manager-dev
network-manager-iodine
network-manager-openconnect
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-strongswan
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc
```

Answer (score 1):

I just switched to Ubuntu so I can't double-check, but was use KDE before.  I'm think the package you're looking to install is `network-manager-l2tp` and then use the network manager GUI to create a new VPN connection.  At least that's what I remember doing.

Comment: There is no `network-manager-l2tp` package available on the official repos, or on any PPAs for Xenial. Does the older version (for example, Utopic) still work for Xenial?